# set the port number in the url for Kiwi IRC

Tags: irc, web-client, kiwi-irc

Is it possible to set the port number in the URL for [Kiwi IRC](https://kiwiirc.com/) already?

This is what I tried: https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.spacetrace.org/spacetrace?port=6666&nick=kiwichatter

The server and nick works like this but not the port.

I couldn't find a hint in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the port with the hostname in the standard way: irc.spacetrace.org:6666

Tip: Add a ? to the nick to generate a random number to stop people getting 'nickname in use' errors.

https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.spacetrace.org:6666/spacetrace/?nick=kiwichatter?

Answer (score -1):

Just type your port next to your nickname you selected. That ought to work.

Comment: Hello Shaanveer. Thanks for contributing. Can you please provide an example of how this would work? Reading your answer, "That ought to work" seems more like it should have been a comment. You will be able to do so with 50 rep. In the future, if you're uncertain, it is a good idea to test if your proposed answer would work before posting.